# Testing date-only data type - Postman

Tags: postman, assertion

I'm new in testing using Postman and I need to know about testing data type for "date-only". 
The assertion below works for string, numeric or integer, but not sure if this also works when using "date-only". Is this a valid assertion?

```
pm.test('To verify data type of relationshipDescription',function(){
      pm.expect(jsonData.relationshipDescription).to.be.a("string"); 

  - - - - this is working

    }); 

pm.test('To verify data type of openDate',function(){
      pm.expect(jsonData.openDate).to.be.a("date-only");
  - - - but need to check if this one is valid test?
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as it's not a valid type in the ChaiJS assertion module, that is what is used by Postman. Is the property a certain known format? You could assert against that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.jsonSchema()` method to assert against the type's format. I don't know what your response body is so this is just an example:

```
{ 
    "openDate": "2020-04-16T08:15:00+00:00" 
}
```

Your test script would look something like this:

```
let schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "openDate"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "openDate": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date-time"
        }
    }
}

pm.test("Schema Check", function () {
    let jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData).to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
});
```

It's using the `date-time` format from the JSON Schema spec - This requires the date and time to fall within a specific format.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times